# How to Import epf data using epfimporter.py provided by apple

Tags: app-store, itunes

i tried using this link http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/epfimporter.html 
**-----------------------**
**Below is the script i executed..**

```
C:\Documents and Settings\freakk>python D:\freakk\Downloads\EPF_Itunes\EPFImporter\E
PFimporter.py \D:\freakk\Downloads\EPF_Itunes\EPFImporter\db\album_popularity_per_
genre
```

**-----------------------**
**But i am getting these errors**

```
2011-10-12 18:24:00,529 [INFO]: Beginning import for the following directories:
    \D:\freakk\Downloads\EPF_Itunes\EPFImporter\db\album_popularity_per_genre
2011-10-12 18:24:00,529 [INFO]: Importing files in \D:\freakk\Downloads\EPF_Itunes
\EPFImporter\db\album_popularity_per_genre
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\freakk\Downloads\EPF_Itunes\EPFImporter\EPFimporter.py", line 452, in <
module>
    main()
  File "D:\freakk\Downloads\EPF_Itunes\EPFImporter\EPFimporter.py", line 435, in m
ain
    fieldDelim=fieldSep)
  File "D:\freakk\Downloads\EPF_Itunes\EPFImporter\EPFimporter.py", line 162, in d
oImport
    fileList = os.listdir(dirPath)
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax i
s incorrect: 'C:\\D:\\freakk\\Downloads\\EPF_Itunes\\EPFImporter\\db\\album_popula
rity_per_genre/*.*'
```

please help me....

Answer (score 1):

See the error log its saying you incorrect syntax

```
C:\\D:\\freakk\\Downloads\\EPF_Itunes\\EPFImporter\\db\\album_popularity_per_genre/*.*
```

and tell me how can D directory be in C? its not getting the correct path to reach there.
 EPFImporter's this code is basically for Mac OS and it assumes that you are in same directory as of EPFImporter.py and in Mac OS everything is in same Directory (as mac is designed).

```
C:\Documents and Settings\freakk>python D:\freakk\Downloads\EPF_Itunes\EPFImporter\EPFimporter.py \D:\freakk\Downloads\EPF_Itunes\EPFImporter\db\album_popularity_per_genre
```

above command will not find either of your EPFImporter.py or album_popularity_per_genre.
change your directory to D from C and go to the directory of EPFImporter.py then try as

```
.....EPFImporter>python EPFImporter.py db\album_popularity_per_genre
```

assuming you are in same folder of EPFImporter, not tested but something like this may work for you. Hope this answer made you a bit clear on this.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved !**

I was trying to import only partial data without main table.
Tried to import flat feed...it worked.

**Code:**

**For Flat Feed**

C:\Documents and Settings\freakk>python c:\epf\epfimporter.py -f c:\epf\db\application-usa-20111012

Note: Don't include file name(application-usa-20111012.txt)..restrict till folder name only (Eg:application-usa-20111012)